# How to know original class name if wrapped into proxy by Spring?

Tags: java, spring, proxy-classes, cglib

I am trying to obtain some classes name by `getClass().getSimpleName()` under `Spring` and it returns something like

```
MyClass$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$SOMEHEX
```

This is probably because `Spring` wraps the class into proxy.

Is there any portable way to obtain original class name?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason why this should not be done?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Spring provides a utility for this.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.html#getUserClass-java.lang.Class-

```
public static Class<?> getUserClass(Class<?> clazz)
```

"Return the user-defined class for the given class: usually simply the given class, but the original class in case of a CGLIB-generated subclass."

Comment: I forgot to mention: this only works for objects proxied by spring. There is no general solution for detecting the target type of any given proxy. The way I solve this is by explicitly defining the target type of my proxies external to the proxy itself.

Comment: Thank you! This worked while other suggestions such as `TargetAwareClass` failed on class cast exception.

Comment: In spring boot: `log.debug(ClassUtils.getUserClass(constraintDescriptor.getAnnotation()).getName());` is `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy153` :-/

Comment: How it works when Spring creates the proxy class using JDK dynamic proxies mechanism instead of cglib?

Comment: @e-info128 : did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 3):

I'd had a similar problem like yours. I'd wanted to write log my repository name at a method of AOP.
When I tried with `ClassUtils.getUserClass()` from upper James' answer, my aop method write log as same as before.

**I solved the problem with `AopProxyUtils.getSingletonTarget()`.**

Plus, I leave following cases for someone who will have same problem.

```
@SpringBootTest
class AopLoggingServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    TestRepository testRepository;

    public void someAopMethod(){
        Class<?> try1 = AopUtils.getTargetClass(testRepository);
        System.out.println("AopUtils.getTargetClass : " + try1);
        Class<?> try2 = ClassUtils.getUserClass(testRepository);
        System.out.println("ClassUtils.getUserClass : " + try2);
        Class<?> try3 = AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(testRepository);
        System.out.println("AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass : " + try3);
        Class<?> finalTry = AopProxyUtils.proxiedUserInterfaces(testRepository)[0];
        System.out.println ("AopProxyUtils.proxiedUserInterfaces[0] : " + finalTry);
    }
}
```

**outputs :**

```
AopUtils.getTargetClass : class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy172
AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass : class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository
ClassUtils.getUserClass : class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy172
AopProxyUtils.proxiedUserInterfaces[0] : interface io.juyeon.test.repository.TestRepository
```