# Get values from 'composed Annotations' in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

With Spring, you can have some kind of composed annotations. A prominent example is the `@SpringBootApplication`-annotation, which is a composite of an  `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`.

I am trying to get all Beans that are affected by a certain annotation, i.e. `ComponentScan`.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10550069/2056452) answer, I am using the following code:

```
for (T o : applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(ComponentScan.class).values()) {
    ComponentScan ann = (ComponentScan) o.getClass().getAnnotation(ComponentScan.class);
    ...
}
```

which does not work, since not all beans, returned by `getBeansWithAnnotation(ComponentScan.class)` are indeed annotated with that annotation, since those that are e.g. annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` are (usually) not.

Now I am looking for some kind of generic way, to retrieve the value of an annotation, even when it is only added as *piece* of another annotation.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, there is a utility set `AnnotatedElementUtils` which allows you to handle those *merged annotations*.

```
for (Object annotated : context.getBeansWithAnnotation(ComponentScan.class).values()) {
    Class clazz = ClassUtils.getUserClass(annotated) // thank you jin!
    ComponentScan mergedAnnotation = AnnotatedElementUtils.getMergedAnnotation(clazz, ComponentScan.class);
    if (mergedAnnotation != null) { // For some reasons, this might still be null.
        // TODO: useful stuff.
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils#findMergedAnnotation is  usually better choice vs org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils#getMergedAnnotation, because the latter uses org.springframework.core.annotation.MergedAnnotations.SearchStrategy#INHERITED_ANNOTATIONS.

Answer (score 1):

it may be CglibProxy. so you can not directly get the Annotation.

```
ClassUtils.isCglibProxyClass(o)
```

for more see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395202/how-to-know-original-class-name-if-wrapped-into-proxy-by-spring)

---

edit,you can add your logic code. find the ComponentScan.

```
if (ClassUtils.isCglibProxyClass(o.getClass())) {
            Annotation[] annotations = ClassUtils.getUserClass(o).getAnnotations();
            for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                ComponentScan annotation1 = annotation.annotationType().getAnnotation(ComponentScan.class);
// in my test code , ComponentScan can get here.for @SpringBootApplication 
                System.out.println(annotation1);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Your guess is right, it is a CglibProxyClass. But the annotation `ComponentScan` is also not present at the `ClassUtils.getUserClass(o)` - `@SpringBootApplication` is present for both classes, `ClassUtils.getUserClass(o)` and `o.getClass()`

Comment: I believe you have 2 choices, #1 know all the Annotations annotated with ComponentScan. From your initial knowledge, SpringBootApplication is one. So if you found that the class is annotated with, and the rest of composed annotations (hopefully spring has document), then you know that the class has ComponentScan using the 'hardcoded' list of annotations. Another way is to (#2) find the ComponentScan annotation of the annotation that is not ComponentScan. As example, this is true: SpringBootApplication.class.isAnnotationPresent(ComponentScan.class)

Comment: @jin, so you basically suggest, to crawl recursively through the tree, composing the annotations to find the one I am looking for. This seems to work, but I cannot retrieve the associated value, yet. However it points in the right direction, just beeing a bit more complicated. It seems, the values are not really set, so I have to check for the *annotations methods, annotated with `AliasFor.class`* to find which values I have to read.

Comment: yes,it is complicate.another way i want to get some information exist in BeanDefinition.but it also complicate.